# Updating RecyclerView when activity resumes?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design

I have a `QuestionActivity` were I show the list of questions in the `RecyclerView`.

I have two action in toolbar

1. Go to downloadedFile activity.
2. Go to favorite activity.

Every thing is OK but when I hit one of that actions and return to `QuestionActivity` the `RecyclerView` couldn't get updated.

So I need to override `OnResume` Method. My question is, How can I update `RecyclerView` in `onResume` Method .

`AdapterRecyclerQuestion` code :

```
public class AdapterRecyclerQuestion extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterRecyclerQuestion.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ModelQuestion> questionha;
    private int lastd;


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //================== Constructor   =========================
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public AdapterRecyclerQuestion(Context context, ArrayList<ModelQuestion> questionha) {
        this.context = context;
        this.questionha = questionha;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //================== view holder  =========================
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView txtTitle;
        private TextView txtDesc;
        private TextView txtCntDown;
        private Button btnDownload;
        private ImageView imgAddFav;
        private ProgressBar prgDownload;

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //================== View holder constructor  ==============
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title_question);
            txtDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_desc_question);
            txtCntDown = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_cnt_down_question_dy);
            btnDownload = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_down_question);
            imgAddFav = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_add_to_fav);
            prgDownload = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.prgDownload);
        }
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //================== on create view holder  ================
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.question_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //================== on bind view holder  =================
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        QuestionDatabaseAdapter questionDatabaseAdapter = new QuestionDatabaseAdapter(holder.itemView.getContext());

        holder.txtTitle.setText(questionha.get(position).getQuestionTitle());
        holder.txtDesc.setText(questionha.get(position).getQuestionDesc());
        holder.txtCntDown.setText(questionha.get(position).getQuestionDownCnt());

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //================== Favorite checking  ====================
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        boolean isFavorite = questionDatabaseAdapter.isQuestionFavorite(questionha.get(position).getQuestionId());

        if (isFavorite)

        {
            holder.imgAddFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_red_700_24dp);
        } else

        {
            holder.imgAddFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_red_a700_24dp);
        }


        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //================== img add fav listener  =================
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        holder.imgAddFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View v) {

                                                    QuestionDatabaseAdapter databaseAdapter = new QuestionDatabaseAdapter(v.getContext());
                                                    boolean isFav = databaseAdapter.isQuestionFavorite(questionha.get(position).getQuestionId());

                                                    if (!isFav) {
                                                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "به لیست علاقه مندی ها اضافه شد", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        holder.imgAddFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_red_700_24dp);
                                                        ModelQuestion question = new ModelQuestion();

                                                        question.setQuestionId(questionha.get(position).getQuestionId());
                                                        question.setQuestionTitle(questionha.get(position).getQuestionTitle());
                                                        question.setQuestionDesc(questionha.get(position).getQuestionDesc());
                                                        question.setQuestionDownLink(questionha.get(position).getQuestionDownLink());
                                                        question.setQuestionDownFileName(questionha.get(position).getQuestionDownFileName());

                                                        databaseAdapter.saveQuestion(question);
                                                    } else {
                                                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "از لیست علاقه مندی ها پاک شد", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        holder.imgAddFav.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_red_a700_24dp);
                                                        databaseAdapter.deleteQuestion(questionha.get(position).getQuestionId());
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
        );
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //================== get item count method  ================
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (questionha.size() == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return questionha.size();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to #SO. Well, What you meant by **It can't restart** ?

Comment: @kiana check your arraylist changes or fill it with new data and do adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: did you try to set (or reset) the adapter on the onResume() method?

Comment: When you push one of these actions and navigate to a new Activity , do you terminate the QuestionActivity ?

Comment: Thanks Anoop  , i need check status of favorite icon and some other works .

Comment: @Vasilisfoo no , if i do this it finish the question activity and goes to the activity before the questionActivity and i don't want this.

Comment: When your activity resumes check for the item changes then update the item list and let the adapter to notify changes using [notifyDataSetChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged.%28%29)

Comment: @kiana can you post the `activity` code where you are setting the adapter?? And from what I understand you want to refresh the list with updated favorite items, right?

Comment: @wolfy are you mean adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()  in onResume ?

Comment: You can start the child activity using `startActivityForResult` then set result in the child activity using `setResult`. In parent activity override `onActivityResult` then update list within same if any changes.

Comment: @AnoopM i have two function in my adapter . 1 check favorite status (it work with notifydatasetchanged) 2. one function to check is file downloaded before or no ? unfortunately 2nd function doesn't update

Comment: no , i write the downloading code in Adapter of question activity in button onclick

Comment: @AnoopM can you explain more clear ?

Comment: @kiana i mean recreate adapter with adapter = new SomethingAdapter(...) and recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Anoop M , I just write the solution work for me .
I write This code in QuestionActivity .

```
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //================== on Resume   ===========
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        adapterRecyclerQuestion.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerQuestion.setAdapter(adapterRecyclerQuestion);
    }
```

Comment: This isn't the right way kiana. Do not force adapter to update it's data unless u really need it. check before action. update only if the item changes. the code u had written will updates your view in every resumes. Say, if your app goes to background from the same screen then when it's comes to foreground it will update your view. tat's perfectly redundant.

Comment: what's your advice ?

Comment: When you ser the adapter. You are forcing recycler view yo be refreshed. So you need to edit data and notify adapter or ser the adapter. But not both

Answer (score 1):

`Loaders` are best suited for such purposes where you want all database changes to be notified and reflected on the UI.

If your are making some changes in database from other two activities and wanted the UI to be updated on QuestionActivity, just make a loader and start it in onResume().

Go through this link to implement a loader:
http://www.grokkingandroid.com/using-loaders-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.
 create a setter for your `ArrayList<ModelQuestion> questionha;` in the Adapter.

```
public void setData(ArrayList<ModelQuestion> data){
    questionha=data;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And call this in your onResume() with the new Data

Remember to call the `notifyDataSetChanged();` or specific `notifiyItemChangedAt(pos)` etc if you know Item at which position has changed an so on. You can choose from - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html